# Nodejs passport session not being saved

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I can't seem to figure out why after authentication user is not saved in session, req.user always seems to be undefined even after successful authentication.
I can see serializeUser being called but req.user always seems to be empty

I am using http, I tried {secure:false} option aswell but unfortunately no success

App js code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors'); 
const http = require('http'); 
const app = express(); 
//Database imports
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session'); 


//Parsers
const cookies = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv/config')
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb', extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb', extended: true}))


app.use(cookies('asdf33g4w4hghjkuil8saef345'));
app.use(cors({ credentials: true }));
//React app
//app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/build'))

require('./passport/passport')(passport);


app.use(session({ secret: 'asdf33g4w4hghjkuil8saef345',cookie : {
    expires: false, 
    },resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: 360*400 // use expires instead of maxAge
    }

 }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, () => {
    console.log('Connected to database');
});  
function isBlocked(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user && req.user.status) {
      // user is authenticated
      next();
    } else {
      // return unauthorized
      res.send(401, "Unauthorized");
    }
  }; 
app.use('/' , require('./routes/auth')); 


var server = http.createServer(app); 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Passport config

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Load User model
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'username' }, (username, password, done) => {
      // Match user
      User.findOne({
        username: username
      }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found' });
        }

        // Match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({username:id}, function(err, user){
        if(!err){
          console.log('no err')
          done(null, user)
        }
        else{
          console.log('error')
          done(err, null)  
        }

        console.log(user)
    })
  })}
```

How I handle login

```
router.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' },),
  function(req, res) { 
    req.session.save(function(){
      res.redirect('/true');
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, You can try using:

```
passport.protected = function protected(req, res, next) {

    try {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log(
          "----AUTHENTICATED ",
          req.session.passport,
          "!!--------"
        );

      } else {
        console.log("----NOT AUTHENTICATED!!--------");
        res.sendStatus(401)
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("ERROR CAUGHT")
      console.log(e)
    }  
  };
```

and you could actually protect your routes as- e.g.

```
app.get("/validatesession", auth.protected, function(req, res) {
});
```

Comment: you're not calling `next` for the success case in the middleware, `try/catch/log` is swallowing the error here as well. You should remove the `try/catch` and let an error middleware catch it higher up.

Comment: that's true, it was just sample code focusing mainly on the function body definition. It can be adjusted as needed.